# Change map type of an MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, folding

I'm trying to develop an interface for the user to change mapType views.  I'd like to implement this by adding a fold effect to the bottom-right corner of the mapview where the user can press or press and drag in the bottom-right corner and the map will fold up just enough to reveal the 3 different mapTypes: regular, hybrid, and satellite.

This is the same functionality that google maps on the iPhone has.  Load the app and notice the 'paper-folding' button in the lower right corner. Press it and witness the effects.  This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there a method to be able to do this? If not, what may be another way to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The [WorldCities](https://github.com/darcyliu/SampleCode/tree/master/WorldCities) sample code from the Apple library uses that implementation and should be a great place to learn how to switch map types.  `MapViewController.m` in particular gives the specifics on it.  As far as getting the curl you are looking for, presenting a modal view controller with your (map type switching controller) using `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` will do just that.  I hope this helps

Comment: This helps learn how to switch map types within the MapViewController.m but I need to know what to put in my .xib to implement the google maps type of functionality...

Comment: How so?  Just to display pins, search, zoom?  Most of the information you will need is found in the [MKMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) and its [Delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204)

Comment: To make searching possible, you need to implement some methods from [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323) as well as its [Delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008324)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using another controller, it is not possible to link directly to the first view controller's `MKMapView` and change the map type of it. Someone told me to use `NSNotification`, but I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm with you - someone told me the same thing but as I look into using NSNotification it seems pretty complicated, setting up the NSNotificationCenter and Delegates and so on....